# Some apps don't swapped alt&win after xmodmap runs? (GUI emacs)

Tags: emacs, xmodmap

I have a mac-book-air. I swapped my Alt  & Win with xmodmap as per [linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86933/swap-alt-and-super#_=_) like so:

```
keycode 64 = Alt_L
keycode 133 = Super_L
remove Mod1 = Alt_L
remove Mod4 = Super_L
add Mod1 = Super_L
add Mod4 = Alt_L
```

Then I apply it via:

```
xmodmap xmodmap.file
```

(btw, I can't seem to apply this directly at system start up, I have to run this maybe 1 min after bootup as otherwise changes don't seem to apply).

Now my Alt+tab works properly in my window manager but for some apps (e.g Emacs or firefox),  but in Emacs meta(alt) and Super(cmd) are not swapped. I.e, s-x and M-x are not swapped.

Do you have any tips/advise/things to try? (
Is it possible to re-map these from inside emacs itself?

Background:
 - I'm using MATE Desktop.
 - I tried Gnome Tweak Tool to swap alt & cmd, but it doesn't seem to function under MATE Desktop.

**[Edit]**
- This issue occurs only in GUI's , e.g emacs/firefox. In terminal it get's the right keys.
- I have tried re-starting emacs/firefox, restarting system, applying the change then start emacs/firefox. No Luck.

Comment: This might not be on-topic there, but I'll just mention there is a emacs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hello, thank you for mentioning this. I updated the question. The issue seems to come up in other apps also, e.g in firefox but not in terminal.